# Laplacian operator defined in $L^2(0,+\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

I have this problem that doesn't seem too simple to me. 
Let be $-\Delta$ the laplacian operator with domain in $C^\infty_0(0,+\infty)\subseteq L^2(0,\infty)$

I want to prove the following:

1. $-\Delta$ is symmetric in his domain;
2. $-\Delta$ is not bounded, nor closed;
3. $-\Delta$ is not essentially self-adjoint in his domain;
4. $-\Delta$ is closable and admits self-adjoint extensions.

For the first, I noted that
$$\langle f,-\Delta g\rangle = -\int_{0}^{\infty}f^{*}(x)g^{\prime\prime}(x)dx=-[g^{\prime}(x)f^{*}(x)]_{0}^{\infty}+\int_{0}^{\infty}(f^{*})^{\prime}(x)g^{\prime}(x)dx= \\ = -[g^{\prime}(x)f^{*}(x)]_{0}^{\infty}+[(f^{*})^{\prime}(x)g(x)]_{0}^{\infty}-\int_{0}^{\infty}(f^{*})^{\prime\prime}(x)g(x)dx$$

The last term is exactly $\langle -\Delta f,g\rangle$, and the boundary terms vanish because of compactness of support of the functions involved.

Regarding the unboundness, I tried to calculate the norm of the operator applied to a bump function sequence like $\exp\{-\frac{n}{1-x^2}\}$ but calculations were horrible; any hint?

The other questions - no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator $-\Delta$ is densely defined on $\mathcal{D}(-\Delta)=\mathcal{C}_{0}^{\infty}(0,\infty)$. If $f,g \in \mathcal{D}(-\Delta)$, then the evaluation terms vanish when integrating by parts in the following:
$$
                     (-\Delta f,g)=(f,-\Delta g)
$$
So $-\Delta$ symmetric on its domain, which is enough to guarantee that $-\Delta$ is closable. The closure $-\Delta^c$ remains symmetric as well. The closure is even positive, which carries over from
$$
                 (-\Delta f,f) = (f',f') \ge 0,\;\;\; f\in\mathcal{D}(-\Delta).
$$
Using integration by parts,
$$
                   ((-\Delta+I)f,e^{-t})= 0,\;\;\; f\in\mathcal{D}(-\Delta).
$$
Therefore $((-\Delta^c+I)f,e^{-t})=0$ for all $f \in \mathcal{D}(-\Delta^c)$. Two facts follow immediately:

1. $-\Delta^c$ cannot be selfadjoint because $-\Delta^c \ge 0$ would then force $-\Delta^{c}+I$ to be surjective and lead to the contradiction that $e^{-t}\equiv 0$.
2. $-\Delta$ cannot be bounded, or $-\Delta^c$ would be bounded, defined everywhere, and selfadjoint, thereby contradicting (1).

The operator $-\Delta$ has selfadjoint extensions because complex conjugation is an isometric, invertible map between $\mathcal{N}((-\Delta)^{\star}-iI)$ and $\mathcal{N}((-\Delta)^{\star}+iI)$.

Comment: Thank you, very clear. Just one thing: could you explain a bit more the last argument? Why isometric kernels would guarantee the existence of self-adjoint extension?

Comment: @Procopius : The existence of a unitary map from $\mathcal{N}((-\Delta)^{\star}+iI)$ onto $\mathcal{N}((-\Delta)^{\star}-iI)$ is necessary and sufficient for the existence of a selfadjoint extension. If you choose an orthonormal basis one of these spaces, then the complex conjugates are an orthonormal basis of the other, which gives you such a unitary map. This is based in the fact that $(A-iI)(A+iI)^{-1}$ is unitary if $A$ is selfajdoint.

Comment: Now I see, thank you very much.

Comment: @Procopius : You're welcome.